# Android Studio java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException on CMake ExternalProject_Add

Tags: android-ndk

I am using Android Studio to build an app with the ndk, it has no java code. The code is written in C++ using CMake to build it. CMake, in turn, includes several projects such as boost etc downloaded, compiled and linked automatically from GitHub via ExternalProject_Add.

This works in Linux but I am now trying to get it to compile in windows Android Studio and I get an error in the middle of the Gradle sync process.

This is the error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
>
> > java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\chris\Documents\pangolin\PrimeMatter\Apps\Dygd\Android\app.cxx\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a_deps\actor_framework-src.git\modules\libcaf_python\third_party\pybind\modules\tools\clang\objects\pack\pack-9372b77cb08267912558dd56012fa92b1022b634.idx
>
> Try:Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

It looks like the pack....idx file has been marked read-only and if I go to the properties of that file to uncheck the read-only property then the compilation can continue to another idx file with the same problem (eventually it starts again with the first file, in a loop).

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution?